# Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "}")

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, heredoc

I am running the following script within a longer html file

```
report_home_space () {
 cat <<- _EOF_
 <h2>Home Space Utilization</h2>
 <pre>$(du -sh /home/*)</pre>
 _EOF_
 return
}
cat <<- _EOF_
<html>
*
  other html here
*
</html>
_EOF_
```

Why I am getting *end of file unexpected* what should I be supposed to do here ?
I have also tried cat << *EOF* but it does not work within my functions, the problem arises only when I insert Here Document inside a function. (I am currently using the bash shell)

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a `}` at the end of your code?

Comment: You indented your second of four `_EOF_` with space(s). That's no allowed.

Comment: I changed it but it does not work, I get the same issue, I had already tried that before.

Comment: Try removing all leading whitespace from inside your heredoc first and see if that helps - [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) is happy after deleting the leading whitespaces at least. If that fixes the problem then you know it's just a formatting error and you just have to get the right syntax (leading tabs instead of spaces in particular as Cyrus suggested).

Comment: When you use `<<-` you can use a TAB to indent the `_EOF_`. But not spaces.

Comment: It worked ( I am a newbie) I guess there was some bug to be fixed because I had to reboot the shell in order to see the applied changes. 
I had already tried to remove spaces but it was not working,once I gave it a reboot it worked. I am currently using wls on window 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to indent the here-doc delimiter, it *must* be with tab characters. In your code, *everything* until the last line of the script is part of the first here-doc.

```
report_home_space () {
  cat <<- _EOF_
        <h2>Home Space Utilization</h2>
        <pre>$(du -sh /home/*)</pre>
        _EOF_
  return
}
```

Here, the 8 spaces used to indent the two lines of the here document and the terminator should be replaced with a literal tab character.

Answer (score -3):

Put the return statement after the closing brace

```
}
return
cat <<- _EOF_
<html>
```

Comment: That's not right. `return` has to be inside the function.